# Android alarm clock app that respects holidays

Tags: android, alarm-clock

I wake up every workday to an alarm on my phone. This works pretty well, but the problem is that it also wakes me up on holidays when I have no work.

Is there an android alarm clock app that lets me select holidays to disable my alarm for?

Comment: I use an alarm clock ([AlarmDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.splunchy.android.alarmclock)) that lets me easily "skip" a single event. Wish it could do that automatically for holidays (or days with a specific keyword in a calendar event). [Smart Alarm](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.tanyu.SmartAlarmFree) promises that, but it seems only for US holidays. [AMdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amdroidalarmclock.amdroid) sounds like a good candidate for all countries; give it a try an report back :)

Comment: Oh, more candidates: [Alarm Calendar Plus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.moyou.acplus) (incl. speaking clock, calendar events as trigger, & more); [AndAlarm](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hyperrate.andalarmad). None of them tried yet (would miss my spoken weather report from *AlarmDroid)* – but certainly sound promising. But that's the end of the list, no more candidates found :)

Comment: Dude you can add holidays if you want manually on Smart Alarm

Answer (score 1):

I've just given [AMdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amdroidalarmclock.amdroid) a try, and it seems to perfectly match your requirements:

[image: AMdroid] [image: AMdroid holidays]
<sup>*AMdroid* lets you define "off days" (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amdroidalarmclock.amdroid); click images for larger variants)</sup>

As the screenshots show, you can define "off days" – days where an alarm should not fire. While you can do so manually, the app also lets you import public holidays: not only specific to your country, but even to your region. Apart from that, it offers a ton of additional features (some of which, such as weather, require the official Google Services to run on your device):

- setup locations. Alarms won't fire if your outside those locations (requires Google Services)
- alarm sound: chose between ringtone and your own MP3, or have *AMdroid* pick a random MP3 from your SD card (works without GServices)
- one-time alarms and repeating ones (chose days or even complex schedules)
- define profiles. Alarms can be assigned a profile (e.g. to honor location or holidays)
- watches your sleep to chose a period of "shallow sleep" to wake you up (so you don't get up on the wrong side of bed; requires GServices)
- Wear support
- more and even more

I have not tested out all the features (the device I'm using it on has no "official Google Services", and there's no public holiday near currently), but it looks very convincing – as does a rating of 4.5+ at *Google Play.*